# How to index a many-to-many relationship in RavenDb?

Tags: ravendb

I have a model in RavenDb that I am trying to assemble into an index that will make identifying Clips for Channels you follow.  Here are the two objects (properties simplified for discussion) I'm attempting to connect:

```
public class Clip {
  string ChannelId
  DateTimeOffset CreatedAt
  string Title
  ...
}

public class FollowerRecord {
  string FollowerId
  string[] ChannelIDs
}
```

Each user in the application has only 1 FollowerRecord.

I'd like to output an index that's shaped like this:

```
public class Index_FollowedClipsByDate {
  string FollowerId
  DateTimeOffset CreatedAt
  string[] Clips 
}
```

I'm a bit stumped on how to load the FollowerRecord, do the many-to-many join between ChannelIds in the FollowerRecord and Clips, and reduce to 1 record per FollowerId and CreatedAt

Comment: Where do you take the CreatedAt from? From which clip?

Comment: Did you see this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69696805

Comment: The CreatedAt is grouped by as well. Both the FollowerId and the CreatedAt are grouping values